# Parse Request Limit - CloudCode

Tags: parse-platform

With the Parse pricing plan, you get 30 requests/second for free. As such, I want to limit the number of requests but I'm not sure what constitutes one request.

I had a function to upload a comment in native iOS. I then rewrote it in CloudCode (for cross platform compatibility). My question is, does this now count as two requests (calling the CloudCode and executing the CloudCode) or is it still just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is 2 requests if you're calling a cloud function which is then saving an object.

Comment: So I guess it's better to write native code to save the object. Thanks.